# For some reason jquery is not working on my page - any ideas?

Tags: jquery, css, joomla, slideshow

I've been asked to fix compatibility issues on an old website using Joomla. The issue is that the current slideshow doesn't show up on mobile devices because the current slideshow is using Flash.

I am replacing the existing slideshow with a jQuery slideshow
http://www.colours.ltd.uk/lazzari/index2.php

I tried loading jQuery externally and internally and nothing happens. I think everything should work, especially since this is the same code I used on another website. And it's really simple.

I even tried this:

```
    if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

}else{

    alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}
```

and it worked, it said jQuery library is loaded. So I have no idea what's going on. What am I missing?

```
    //Slideshow
$(function() {
        $("#slideshow1 > li:gt(0)").hide();

 setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slideshow1 > li:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow1');
        },  6000);  
        });
```

Comment: Try this: **alert( "You are running jQuery version: " + jQuery.fn.jquery );**, if it works, jQuery is loading but there is a conflict with the $ variable that you need to sort out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prototype.js is redefining the `$` variable

Answer (score 3):

Joomla pages typically include mootools, which may takeover the `$` variable.

Try using `jQuery` in place of `$`